# How can I pass a variable from functions.php to the template file in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't access my variables inside my template file (see comment below). 
thanks in advance for the help.

*functions.php:*

```
$mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$maxpost = $loop->max_num_pages;
```

*template.php:*

```
$args = array(
          'post_type' => 'publications',
          'posts_per_page' => 2,
      );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>

    <?php if ($query->have_posts()) : ?>
      <div id="posts">
        <?php while ($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>
          <section class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2  publications-section tagged-posts post">
            <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) : ?>
            <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>">
              <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-push-8 publications-section-image" style="background-image:url('<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>');"></div>
            </a>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-pull-4">
             <h2><a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $post->ID ); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
             <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
             <small><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_contact", true); ?></small>
             <small class="pub-tags pub"> <span><?php the_terms( $post->ID,'mytag','',' '); ?></span></small>
           </div>
          </section>
        <?php echo $mypage; endwhile; wp_reset_postdata();  ?>
      </div>

      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2" id="pub-btn-section">
        <input type="submit" class="btn" id="loadmore" name="" value="Submit">
      </div>
    <?php endif;  ?>
```

Comment: show the complete code of functions.php which hook are you using for functions.php's code.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to **declare your global variable** in functions.php outside of any functions first, and you do this *without* the global keyword.
2. When you want to **reference the global variable** when its out of scope (e.g. in a function, in another file), that's when you used the `global` keyword.

**functions.php**:

```
// declare your global variables
$mypage = 0;
$mymax = 0;

function myfunction(){
    global $mypage,$mymax; // reference your global variables

    $mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
    $mymax = $loop->max_num_pages;
}
```

Now you should be able to access it in template.php, depending on what hook you are using (as long as that hook isn't called too early.

**NOTE:**

The use of global variables is strongly discouraged, so consider why you're doing it this way... could the logic of your code be changed, or a custom function be used instead??

Another option is to use `get_query_var()` and `set_query_var()`- although these are intended for passing parameters instead of on the querystring.

***functions.php***

```
$mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
set_query_var("mypage", $mypage );    // set your variable
```

***template.php***

```
$mypage = get_query_var("mypage"); // get the variable
```

Again, these depend on where in the sequence of actions the hook you are using is.

**Update**:

If your paging variables are in a function that includes a *template_part*, in that case you would use `include(locate_template('your-template-part.php'));` after setting them to pass them to that file.

Comment: variable doesn't update in the template file, it just says 0

Comment: @jordan Can you update your question with the code you are using now, including the action & function where you are trying to set the values for $mypage & $mymax

Comment: @jordan You are using AJAX which makes this a different question entirely. Therefore I suggest you rollback this question to the previous version so the answers still apply to that question for other users with *that* issue, and post a *new* question about passing parameters via AJAX.

Answer (score -1):

let's assume that your are used the [`get_template_part()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/) function to include template in `function.php` file.

now pass some value with this you can used the [`set_query_var()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/set_query_var) function above the `get_template_part()`

> `functions.php` code

```
$mypage = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$mymax = $loop->max_num_pages;
set_query_var( 'mypage', absint( $mypage ) );
set_query_var( 'mymax', absint( $mymax) );
get_template_part(  'The slug name for the generic template', $name = null  );
```

> In `template.php` file, we need to access the `$mypage` and `mymax` variable directly

```
echo $mypage;
echo $mymax;
```