# Pulling Data from a PHP file into a PHP file [Wordpress]

Tags: wordpress, markdown, custom-wordpress-pages

**EDIT:** I did it. I was able to pull in the data, but not sure if this is the right method, but it is working.

I added this to my template file and it works:

> include(locate_template('template-parts/data/lemon/data-lemon.php'));

Saw it from this posting: [How can I pass a variable from functions.php to the template file in WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46440500/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-from-functions-php-to-the-template-file-in-wordpress)

So I have a client that does not want a page builder or Gutenberg, but wants to be able to change the data when needed. This person is not tech savvy, so giving them access to files is not a good idea.

So I thought about using markdown files or even variables. I could have a template, then pull the variables from another template. This way they can change the data but have no access to the file structure.

Here is what I have:

> 

```
<!-- Variable for Data -->
<?php locate_template( 'template-parts/data/lemon/data-lemon.php', true ); ?>


<!-- Hero Section -->
<section id="hero" class="flex flex-col md:flex-row gap-4">

    <div id="col-left" class="basis-2/5">
        <h3>
            <?php echo $heroSubtitle; ?>
        </h3>
        <h1>
            <?php echo $heroTitle; ?>
        </h1>
        <p>
            <?php echo $heroDescription; ?>
        </p>
        <div id="button-wrapper" class="flex flex-row gap-2">
            <button class="bg-yellow-500 text-white px-4 h-[40px]">
                <a href="/" class="text-gray-900 hover:text-white active:text-white">Buy Lemon</a>
            </button>
            <button class="bg-white border-solid border-grey-100 border-2 px-2 h-[40px]">
                <a href="/">
                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 14" width="24" height="24">
                        <path fill="none" d="M0 0h24v24H0z"/>
                        <path d="M16.004 9.414l-8.607 8.607-1.414-1.414L14.589 8H7.004V6h11v11h-2V9.414z"/>
                    </svg>
                </a>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="col-right" class="basis-3/5">
        <figure>
            <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>\assets\img\progessive-img.png" alt="" title="" />
        </figure>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then ... I have the variable or data file like this [This is inside the data-lemon.php file]:

```
<?php
    // Variable for the lemon page
    $heroSubtitle = 'Meet Lemon';
    $heroTitle = 'Build a better site for your business.';
    $heroDescription = '[short description here] blorem blipsum dolor sit bamat minim mollit non deserunt ullamco lorem ipsum.';
?>
```

As you can see in the example I have tried "locate_template()", but I have also tried "get_template_parts" with no luck.

"get_template_parts" works great for getting oher blocks of data into the template file, but not when it comes to variables.

Any idea of what I am doing wrong or if this is even possible.

Cheers

Comment: You shouldn't need to use `locate_template` at all. You could most likely use `include 'template-parts/data/lemon/data-lemon.php'` or `include_once 'template-parts/data/lemon/data-lemon.php'` - Another way this could be done, rather than a markdown file is use custom meta fields on each page, that you can grab the data from. The client doesn't need to be tech savvy, just enter the information. If you haven't, look into Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: Thanks for the reply back .. yes, I was looking and working with ACF last night. I think that is a better way to go at it, plus less work. =)